# Coping data in number of rows

Tags: javascript

```
<script>
function copy_data(val){
 var a = document.getElementById(val.id).value
 document.getElementById("copy_to").value=a
}
</script>
```

i am using this code in head portion for copying data from one text box to another. I need to know what can i do to copy data in number of fields in different rows to copy data from one column to another of the same row?

Comment: Could you post an example of your `HTML`?

Answer (score 0):

You can choose among popular javascript libraries and use their css based selectors to query your fields. A couple of examples:

- JQuery's $: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/
- dojo.query: http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojo/query.html

As a result of the query you obtain an array like object (depending of the library) which gives you the ability to iterate over, and do your copying.